# Views and Panels: Exclude already displayed items from view

Tags: views, panels

I have two views on the frontpage, first one is a gallery and it should show only articles which have "promoted to frontpage" checked. The second view should show all the articles except the ones show in the first view.

I saw this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170572/how-to-exclude-an-item-from-a-view-if-it-appears-in-another-view-on-the-same-pag), but the answer does not help me, because in the second view, i don't want to exclude the "promoted to frontpage" articles, i just want to exclude the first 6 of them, all the other should appear mixed up with the other articles.

I also found this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52529/multiple-views-on-a-page-how-to-exclude-already-shown-nodes), but as i use panels, i think it's not working for me.

How can i pass varibales from one view to another, or how to setup conditions to work like that? Or how can i set up more complex filters in a view, like

(promoted_to_frontpage== 1 && offset == 6) || (promoted_to_frontpage == 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok in the end, i was able to handle it with the answer of the maclean, which allowed me to configure everything in the views itself:

I have got two different views, not different displays, so in the first view, my gallery, i ad the Content:nid to the available fields and set it to not visible.

In the second view, i use - as he described - the contextual filter content:nid.

[image]

Provide default value, enter the code and - also as he described - Under "More" check both "Allow multiple values" and "Exclude".

Answer (score 1):

If your views are not using pager then its easy just add a contextual filter with the following php code

```
$offset = 5
```

However, it is very unlikely. The best path is to use `hook_views_pre_view($view)`

Something like this

```
function YOUR-MODULE-NAME-HERE_views_pre_view($view, &$items) // note the '&' here!
{
  global $pager_page_array;

  // if this is our view...
  if ($views->name == "my-view-name" 
       // ..and we're on its first page...
       && $pager_page_array[0] == 0 ) {
    $items = array_splice($items, 0, 5); // ...then eat up the first 5 nodes
  }
}
```

Comment: but what happens on the second page?

Comment: if you are using pager, then you should use the second snippet

Comment: Thanks for your help, in the end, i solved it with the PHP-Code in the contextual filter